# Ошибка в xml файле AAPT: error: unbound prefix

Tags: android, xml

В xml теге `AAPT: error: unbound prefix`. Ошибку выводит в самое первой строчке `<Button`. Вот отрывок кода, в котором выводит ошибку:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button_back"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/back"
android:background="@drawable/button_stroke_black95_press_white"
android:textSize="24sp"
androi:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:textColor="@color/black95"
android:textAllCaps="false"/>
```

Comment: В xml теге Button, ошибку выводит в самой первой строчке (<Button)

Comment: Первую строчку не добавил случайно, вот она: <Button

Answer (score 0):

У вас неверный префикс в строке 7

**androi**:paddingLeft="5dp